# Fork system call not exiting

Tags: c, unix, fork, system-calls

I've run the following code :

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After printing the word "Hello" 8 times, the program is not exiting. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Why do say it is not exiting? What is the symptom that make you think that?

Comment: I suppose you get lots of *hellos* - Perhaps time to read the manual for `fork`

Comment: After running the program,it is still not redirecting to the '$' sign in terminal.

Comment: But why it expects another command from me? Isn't it supposed to exit?

Comment: Try pressing enter, then man fork.

Comment: the program is using an implicit declaration of `fork()`.  That is because the code is missing a header file.  suggest: insert the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: to avoid any production of 'zombie' programs, each 'parent' process needs to call `waitpid()` on the child process it created via the call to `fork()`.  The code 'should' also be checking the returned value from the call(s) to `fork()` to catch any call failures.

Comment: I would expect that the first process exits before the last of its progeny, so the command line prompt is lost in amongst the outputs (the stream of 'hello' lines).  The shell is probably sitting there waiting for you to type something.  Your code doesn't need `<sys/types.h>` (modern POSIX systems seldom need it explicitly), but it should use `<unistd.h>` to declare `fork()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an accidentally interesting way to calculate 2^3. The first fork makes the second fork happen twice and they each make the third fork happen twice and all 8 children run printf! The 8 processes do exit, but your prompt is lost in the noise.

As the commenters implied, you are fundamentally misunderstanding what fork() is and what it is doing. But along the way you made an interesting toy, so bravo!